# Symfony 2.7 form choice значение "по умолчанию" для списка чекбоксов

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony

Не могу разобраться как решить проблему. Есть контроллер, в нем создаётся форма:

```
    $options = [
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ];
    /** @var FormBuilder $searchForm */
    $searchForm = $this->get('form.factory')
        ->createNamedBuilder('i', 'form', [], $options)
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('frontpage'))
        ->setMethod('GET');
    $searchForm
        ->add('state', 'text')
        ->add('city', 'choice', [
            'choices' => [1, 2, 3],
            'required' => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'empty_data' => [1]
        ]);

    $form = $searchForm->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $data = $form->getData();
```

Идёт следующий запрос: `/?i[state]=test`

В `$data` получаю `['state' => 'test', 'city' => []]`
Если изменить

```
'expanded' => false,
```

То, всё нормально. Проблема в том, что мне надо `expanded true`, т.к. на фронте это список чекбоксов.

Comment: "Решил" тем что переопределил шаблоны twig для формы, сделал вместо select - checkbox. Но хотелось бы узнать есть ли нормальное решение для empty_data при expanded = true и multiple = true?

Answer (score 1):

У меня давно была похожая проблема.
Там была какая-то проблема в ChoiceType, пришлось создать свой тип поля.
Для него создать собственный темплейт twig, скопировав twig код из стандартного темплейта для choicetype (expanded вариант) и чуток видоизменив его.

Еще для чего-то добавил event listener (уже не помню для чего):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface;
//...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function(FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            /** @var ChoiceListInterface $choiceList */
            $choiceList =  $options['choice_list'];
            $values = (array) $event->getData();
            $indices = $choiceList->getIndicesForValues($values);
            $result =  count($indices) > 0 ? array_combine($indices, $values) : array();

            $event->setData($result);
        },9);
    }
```